# How to retrieve TIMESTAMP value from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, datetime, timestamp

I have this in my MODEL:

```
public Timestamp getDateadded() {
    return dateadded;
}

/**
 * @param dateadded the dateadded to set
 */
public void setDateadded(Timestamp dateadded) {
    this.dateadded = dateadded;
}
```

Which is used by my Data Access Object to get and set the time from the database:

```
while(rs.next())
         {
             comment = new Comment();
             comment.setDetails(rs.getString("details"));
             comment.setDateadded(rs.getTimestamp("dateadded"));
             comment.setUrgency(rs.getInt("urgency"));
             commentList.add(comment);
         }
```

After getting the values, the values are set to an arrayList which is forwarded to a page and output using JSTL.

However, I CANNOT figure out why it does not show ANY result.

DEBUGGING TRIED:
I printed a non-null arrayList and got something like this [Models.Project@17735867] and when I print the value of COMMENT (the one that has error) the output of the print is just []

So that means there is an error in the arrayList.

Would any of you know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I have no idea how this problem is related to retrieving the timestamp. It look like that your `rs.next()` never returned `true`. The problem is then not in the code shown so far at all. It's likely in the SQL string or the way how you stored/returned the list. On an unrelated note, you should not use `java.sql.Timestamp` in your model. Use it in DAO classes only. Use `java.util.Date` in your model instead. In the DAO, you can just upcast (the `Timestamp` is a subclass of util `Date`).

Answer (score 0):

Put debug on `ResultSet`, make sure its having data or  its going inside while loop code?

Comment: what do you mean put debug? i dont think rs has data because when i print the result of the array, it only has a [ ] rather than a [Models.Project@17735867] from arrays which have data.

Comment: if rs is not having data..List will be empty. could you please describe the issue your facing?...